# How to override base class render fragments from deriver class in Blazor

Tags: blazor

I would like to define a base page  that all classes should derive from in Blazor but have problems in overriding templates.

ie.

> base-page.razor
>
> ```
>   @if(ShowData)
>   {
>      <div>
>           @TitleTemplate
>      </div>
>      <div>
>          @BodyTemplate
>     </div>
>   }
>   else
>   {
>     <Spinner />
>   }
>
>   @code {
>      [Parameter]
>      public RenderFragment HeaderTemplate {get;set;}
>      [Parameter]
>      public RenderFragment BodyTemplate {get;set;}
>      protected bool ShowData {get;set; = false;
>   }
> ```
>
> derived-page.razor
>
> ```
>   <HeaderTemplate>
>      some html for header here...
>   </HeaderTemplate>
>   <BodyTemplate>
>      some body html here...
>   </BodyTemplate>
>   
>   @code {
>       private object Data = new();
>       protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
>       {
>           Data = await someService.GetData();
>           base.ShowData = true;
>           StateHasChanged()
>       }
>   }
> ```

The final should be a page that has all the RenderFragments overridden in derived page.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Basically `ComponentBase`, the standard component used by the world, isn't designed to handle the functionality you want to implement.

You have two options.

1. Shoehorn the necessary functionality into ComponentBase.  This answer shows how to build out a template using the existing `ComponentBase` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74613188/13065781
2. Build your own base component that is designed to handle the wrapper functionality.  There's a repo of mine here that shows you how to do that - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo.ComponentWrapper