# Render Mode in MainLayout.razor Blazor 8?

Tags: razor, blazor

I am using interactive server with per component/per page setting.

I am trying to use https://havit.blazor.eu/components/HxMessenger and it is telling me to put this code in the MainLayout

```
<HxMessenger Position="ToastContainerPosition.TopEnd" />
```

but nothing works and I suspect it is because there is no render mode set for the MainLayout but I don't know how to set it ever time I try to specify a render mode I crashes with

> InvalidOperationException: Cann pass the paramter 'body' to component
> mainlayout with rendermode InteractiveServerRenderMode'. This is
> because the paramater is of type RenderFragment which is arbitary code
> and canot be searlized

Comment: <HxMessenger @rendermode="..." Position="ToastContainerPosition.TopEnd" />

Answer (score 1):

You can't add the render mode to Layouts.  You need to go global and add it to `App`.

```cs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Blazor.Server.SSR.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer"/>
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What happens if I don't want to go global, though?

Comment: If you use something like `HxMessenger`  then I'm guessing you want to alert the user  when things happen.  That's not going to happen on SSR or Streamed pages.      If you want a mixed mode site where you have both SSR pages and interactively rendered pages then put `HxMessenger` in the interactive pages.  The reason the documentation says put it in the layout is so that it's available on all the pages and you only need to add it once.

Comment: Which leads to the question of how do I build a wrapper component that contains the `HxMessenger` and I inherit from for all my active pages.  See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74611871/define-html-and-blazor-components-just-once-for-multiple-pages