# MudBlazor Dialog not showing .NET 8

Tags: c#, blazor, dialog, mudblazor

I'm learning blazor and am working on a relatively simple blazor app with MudBlazor and .NET 8. I'm at a bit of a loss as to why this isn't working. I want to open a simple dialog, and just as the example in the [documentation](https://mudblazor.com/components/dialog#usage) suggests, I've added `<MudDialogProvider />` to my `MainLayout.razor` and defined the dialog as follows:

**Test.razor**

```
@inject IDialogService DialogService
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<h3>Test</h3>
<MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="@Add">Add</MudButton>
    
@code { 
  private void Add() {
    var options = new DialogOptions { CloseOnEscapeKey = true };
    DialogService.Show<TestDialog>("Test", options);
  }
}
```

**TestDialog.razor**

```
<MudDialog>
  <DialogContent>
    Dialog Test
  </DialogContent>
  <DialogActions>
    <MudButton Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="Submit">Ok</MudButton>
  </DialogActions>
</MudDialog>

@code {
  [CascadingParameter] MudDialogInstance MudDialog { get; set; }

  void Submit() => MudDialog.Close(DialogResult.Ok(true));
}
```

**MainLayout.razor**

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<MudThemeProvider />
<MudDialogProvider />
<MudSnackbarProvider />

<MudLayout>
  <MudAppBar>
    <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.Start" OnClick="@((e) => DrawerToggle())" />
    My Application
  </MudAppBar>
  <MudDrawer @bind-Open="@_drawerOpen">
    <NavMenu />
  </MudDrawer>
  <MudMainContent>
    @Body
  </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>

@code {
  bool _drawerOpen = true;

  void DrawerToggle() {
    _drawerOpen = !_drawerOpen;
  }
}
```

When pressing the view button, nothing happens and no error is throw. I've also tried adding `@rendermode InteractiveServer` to `TestDialog.razor` but  that didn't change anything either. When debugging, it reaches `DialogService.Show` with now issue and does not throw an error. For most other people with this issue it seems to be the missing `<MudDialogProvider />` that solves it but I have already had that added.

If I try to add `@rendermode InteractiveServer` to `MainLayout.razor`, I get the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot pass the parameter 'Body' to component 'MainLayout' with rendermode 'InteractiveServerRenderMode'. This is because the parameter is of the delegate type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment', which is arbitrary code and cannot be serialized
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77614553/render-mode-in-mainlayout-razor-blazor-8) suggested adding the render mode to `App.razor` instead, which works fine but doesn't help with the dialog issue either.

My app is currently set up to run just with the Interactive Servcer render mode. Is there something really obvious here I am overlooking?

Comment: what does your `MainLayout.razor` look like?

Comment: @RBee I have edited the question and added it. I think it's pretty much what was generated except for the dialog provider and the snackbar provider

Comment: Try adding the `@rendermode InteractiveServer` on your `MainLayout` aswell.

Comment: @RBee adding it to `MainLayout.raozr` results in errors, however I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77614553/render-mode-in-mainlayout-razor-blazor-8) post describing that you can add the render mode to `App.razor`. I've tried that and it hasn't changed anything regarding the dialog

Comment: Oh wait a minute so you're using custom divs instead of the MudLayout components mentioned in the [documentation](https://mudblazor.com/getting-started/layouts#basic-layout) Try using the build in layout components

Comment: Also add the errors you receive when adding `@rendermode` to `MainLayoutto` the question.

Comment: @RBee Oh I didn't even notice that, I assumed the generated template would already include what layout features there are. I've dabbled around with your suggestions and added what you requested. But I've found [this](https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor?tab=readme-ov-file#prerequisities) note in the prerequisities for MudBlazor in .NET 8 and while I'm not quite sure what BSS means, could it be that InteractiveServer is just not supported for this type of stuff yet?

Comment: BSS i.e. Blazor Server Side. That note means you need to have interactivity in all `MudBlazor` components with a `@rendermode` either server or wasm in order for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `<MudDialogProvider />` in your **Test.razor** file instead of the **MainLayout.razor**, that's what is working for me to get the dialog displayed.